Add a space around equals-sign if not already whitespace
I am trying to work out a Perl regex for adding in a space around equals sign ("=") - but only if there isn't a space there already:
var myVariable="thisValue" -> var myVariable = "thisValue"
var mySecondVariable ="thisValue" -> var mySecondVariable = "thisValue"
var myThirdVariable= "thisValue" -> var myThirdVariable = "thisValue"

I have managed to replace valid characters with a space.
I have managed to have double-spaces before a "="... and nothing after.

What if there's already more than one space before/after the equal sign? Should they all be preserved?

Have you tried using negative lookarounds to match = not surrounded by space?

This replaces all optional whitespace around = (or none) with a single space before and after =:
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/\s*=\s*/ = /g;
    print;
}

__DATA__
var myVariable="thisValue" -> var myVariable = "thisValue"
var mySecondVariable ="thisValue" -> var mySecondVariable = "thisValue"
var myThirdVariable= "thisValue" -> var myThirdVariable = "thisValue"

Prints:
var myVariable = "thisValue" -> var myVariable = "thisValue"
var mySecondVariable = "thisValue" -> var mySecondVariable = "thisValue"
var myThirdVariable = "thisValue" -> var myThirdVariable = "thisValue"


alternatively, to more closely follow the "adding": s/\s?=\s?/ = /g (or s/ ?= ?/ = /g if literal space only)

Easy.
while(<>) {
    $_ =~ s/([^ ])=/$1 =/;
    $_ =~ s/=([^ ])/= $1/;
    print;
}

The [^ ]=, which means "not space followed by equal sign". But since [^ ] will by itself eats a symbol - you will need to "preserve it"
by using parenthesis, and reuse that symbol by using $1.

while clear, this is inefficient since it involves 2 passes over the input when only one pass is required

I am not sure about all the allowed characters for a variable and if those can span multiple lines.
But if you don't want to cross lines while matching, and there has to be at least a single non whitespace character before and after the equals sign that itself is not an equals sign itself:
([^\s=])\h*=\h*([^\s=])

The regex matches:

([^\s=]) Capture group 1, match a single non whitespace char other than =
\h*=\h* Match an equals sign between optional horizontal whitespace chars
([^\s=]) Capture group 2, the same as group 1

See a regex demo.
If there can be newlines, you can use \s* and you could make [^\s=] more specific for allowed characters. Note that if you want to parse Perl code, you might also look into a parser.
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/([^\s=])\h*=\h*([^\s=])/$1 = $2/g;
    print;
}

__DATA__
var myVariable="thisValue"
var mySecondVariable ="thisValue"
var myThirdVariable= "thisValue"

Output
var myVariable = "thisValue"
var mySecondVariable = "thisValue"
var myThirdVariable = "thisValue"

